# Zootool - export content

Tags: export, backup, download

I'm using the zootool.com webapplication to store information about my favourite blog posts in an easily searchable way.

I am worried that should there be a corruption of their database, I would lose all data.

Is there a way I could export the contents in the form of e.g. an XML file (I mean the list of stored web pages and applied tags) that I could download and backup myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export your zoo via **Settings > Sync > Download bookmark file**. Exported files should be compatible with Safari, Firefox, Delicious and more.

Comment: Maybe I am clueless, but I stared at the Settings dialog without seeing a Sync option. Actually, it is at the top of the dialog (dark toolbar over dark background, text is dimmed out; stupid design choice) and the icon is the green round one...

Comment: Yes, the **Download bookmark file** button is located on the **Sync** tab inside the window that appears after you click on the **Settings** menu item.

Comment: It was a useful information none less, it pushed me in the right direction! Too bad we don't have enough reputation, yet, to create a zootool tag... And too bad we cannot make it as a way to ask a moderator to validate it.